# SQL Server append column while merging

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have requirement to append a column data and at same time I need to check if primary key already exists. So  I used following to check for whether primary key exist or not then update or create respectively. But I want to add data to Meeting column if it already exist. Can anyone suggest solution?

```
MERGE
  INTO tblStatus WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
  USING
    (SELECT '2018-06-18' AS sdate, 15813 AS Meeting) AS source (sdate, Meeting)
  ON
    (target.sdate = source.sdate)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
      [tblStatus] SET Meeting = 12000 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT                                                 
      (sdate, Meeting) VALUES ('2018-06-18', 15813);
```

Comment: Found answer. I need to use "Meeting += 12000" . It is append like many programming languages.

Comment: . . The more typical solution would be `SET Meeting = Meeting + 12000`.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. It is giving ambiguous column name error when I use as you suggested. How can I update query such that the column name refers to row where sdate matches '2018-06-18'

Comment: . . Then qualify the column name on the right side of the expression.